# Angular JS filter not equals

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-filter

Seems like a very basic question but I can't get the syntax right..

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="question in newSection.Questions | filter:Id != '-1'; " ng-mouseenter="hover = true" ng-mouseleave="hover = false">
    <div href="#" editable-text="question.Text">{{question.Text}}</div>
</li>
```

All I want is to show all the questions where id is NOT -1.
What am I doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: you need to write a custom filter which takes checks the question.id != -1. Also I think your error is that id is an attribute of question

Comment: @EliteOctagon You can do it - see my answer below.

Comment: Dit you look at the documentation? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter
In the part where `expression` is explained (second p at *Usage* -> *arguments* )

`filter: {Id: "!-1"}` or someting like that shoud do the trick

Answer (score 173, accepted):

The syntax is just a little off, try:

```
<li class="list-group-item"
    ng-repeat="question in newSection.Questions | filter:{ Id: '!-1'}"
    ng-mouseenter="hover = true" ng-mouseleave="hover = false">

    <div href="#" editable-text="question.Text">{{question.Text}}</div>
</li>
```

See a little JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/3845/

**Edit:**

Example with variables:

```
<script> var invalidId = '-1'; </script>
<li class="list-group-item"
    ng-repeat="question in newSection.Questions | filter:{ Id: '!' + invalidId}"
    ng-mouseenter="hover = true" ng-mouseleave="hover = false">

    <div href="#" editable-text="question.Text">{{question.Text}}</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Can this somehow also work for variables? [This slight modification of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/6144/) places the "not-equal" quantity in a variable, instead of a constant, and it won't work anymore.

Comment: Well you probably need to writer your own filter function, let's call it `checkForX` and then use it like `... | filter:checkForX` and return true or false if there is a match...

Comment: @Domi, i've posted a more general answer that answers your question. Check it out when you have the time

Comment: To get this working with variables, I had to declare an additional string variable in Javascript and preprend a "!", e.g. var notValid = -1; var filterString = '!' + notValid; Then in the HTML use filter: { Id: filterString}

Comment: @Tielman, no need in declaring extra variables. This works well: "filter: {id: '!' + notValid}"

Comment: This will also filter out any `Id` which contains `-1` as a substring, such as `-11` or `2-1`. To reliably check that the `Id` is not `-1` you should write a small comparator function and use that as the filter.

Comment: @MichaelRose, check this fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/33383/` , why last one is not display in list, event last one id is -12 not -1 ??

Comment: The answer above by @Tielman worked for me, thank you for posting!

Answer (score 21):

Although @Michael Rose answer works for this case, i don't think it will if you try to filter not equal some object/variable

In that case you could use:

**JS**:

```
filterId = -1
```

**HTML:**

```
<li ng-repeat="question in newSection.Questions | filter: !{ Id: filterId}">
</li>
```

---

An even more nested case:

**JS**:

```
someQuestion = {
   someObject: {
     Id: 1
   }
}
newSection.Questions = [someQuestion]
```

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="question in newSection.Questions | filter: !{someObject : {Id: -1} }">
</li>
```

Comment: This syntax doesn't work for me: !{ Id: -1} but the alternative answer works great: { Id:'!-1'}. Perhaps it is/was a version difference?

Comment: Could be. What version are you using?