# AngularJS : ng-repeat filter when value is greater than

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple ng-repeat that throws out data, one of fields it displays is NumberOfStamps:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="list in Data.Items ">
   <td><a href=" {[{list.Title}]} {[{list.ForeName}]} {[{list.SurName}]}</a></td>
   <td>(Date of Birth {[{list.Dob}]})</td>
   <td>{[{list.NumberOfStamps}]}  stamps</td>
</tr>
```

Example output:

```
Mr Adam Happy  Date of Birth 01/6/1984     16 stamps
Mr Adam Sad    Date of Birth 24/11/1975    0 stamps
Mr Adam Green  Date of Birth 02/1/1963     1 stamps
Mr Adam Red    Date of Birth 21/1/1951     12 stamps
Mr Adam Blue   Date of Birth 28/10/1998    0 stamps
Mr Adam Brown  Date of Birth 25/9/2010     0 stamps
Mr Adam Black  Date of Birth 24/8/1954     21 stamps
Mr Adam Violet Date of Birth 17/5/1942     54 stamps
```

How can i modify this ng-repeat to only show records where the NumberOfStams is > 0? I've tried:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="list in Data.Items | filter:{NumberOfStamps > 0}">
   <td><a href=" {[{list.Title}]} {[{list.ForeName}]} {[{list.SurName}]}</a></td>
   <td>(Date of Birth {[{list.Dob}]})</td>
   <td>{[{list.NumberOfStamps}]}  stamps</td>
</tr>
```

Expected output:

```
Mr Adam Happy  Date of Birth 01/6/1984     16 stamps
Mr Adam Green  Date of Birth 02/1/1963     1 stamps
Mr Adam Red    Date of Birth 21/1/1951     12 stamps
Mr Adam Black  Date of Birth 24/8/1954     21 stamps
Mr Adam Violet Date of Birth 17/5/1942     54 stamps
```

Comment: can you put it in a plnkr or fiddle please

Comment: @guru - is there not enough information there??

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Create a predicate function on the relevant scope:

```
$scope.greaterThan = function(prop, val){
    return function(item){
      return item[prop] > val;
    }
}
```

As a first argument, it takes a property name on the object. The second argument is an integer value.

Use it in your view like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="list in Data.Items | filter: greaterThan('NumberOfStamps', 0)">
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3B1chZGdZQhTVKMduMIb?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the post and link, whats the benefit of using/creating a predicate over other people solutions?

Comment: The solution is best expressed as a *filter*, close to what you originally tried. One answer currently posted is not a filter, and the other only negates 0 values - it doesn't do a greater than comparison.

Comment: I understand your comments, and your code is neat and simple.. Only reason i questioned it because i 'expected' Angular to have a 'one or two word' way of doing it.

Comment: I was trying to wonder how to do conditionals in filter. And this helped me alot. :)

Comment: This solution is very elegant; thank you very much. Just learned a better way to do something.

Answer (score 44):

You can create a filter with ng-if like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="seller in sellers" ng-if="seller.sales > 0" >{{ seller.name }}</li>
```

Comment: I personally prefer this approach rather than using the filters as it gives a bit more flexibility.

Comment: This is easy to implement but becomes annoying when we rely on ng-repeat $index integrity, for example if $first / $last / etc doesn't have seller.sales then we can't apply special markup which is a common use case for me.

Comment: I know this approach is better than creating a custom filter.Now how can I get the count of sellers after ng-if applied in template?

Answer (score 2):

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="Data.Items in list = ( Data.Item | filter:{NumberOfStamps : !0}">
   <td><a href=" {[{list.Title}]} {[{list.ForeName}]} {[{list.SurName}]}</a></td>
   <td>(Date of Birth {[{list.Dob}]})</td>
   <td>{[{list.NumberOfStamps}]}  stamps</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: In your post youve got Data.Items  and  Data.Item... Is it Item or Items??

Comment: My mistake: Data.Items

Comment: !0 will return a false instead of a number, so won't work for numbers

Comment: | filter:{ NumberOfStamps: '!0' } 
[works with numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22666687).. some issues but works

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be to remove the items that do not meet the criterai from the DOM using [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="list in Data.Items ">
    <td ng-if="list.NumberOfStamps > 0"><a href=" {[{list.Title}]} {[{list.ForeName}]} {[{list.SurName}]}</a></td>
    <td ng-if="list.NumberOfStamps > 0">(Date of Birth {[{list.Dob}]})</td>
    <td ng-if="list.NumberOfStamps > 0">{[{list.NumberOfStamps}]}  stamps</td>
</tr>
```

Because [you cannot have a div in a tr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051219/div-into-a-tr-is-it-correct) you have to ng-if the td's seperately, which is not optimal if you have alot of td's

Comment: I think there is an extra or miss }} in your ng-if

Comment: This isnt working in my application. I think it has something to do with a DIV directly below a TR as thats incorrect MARKUP

Comment: @OamPsy you are correct, excuses. I edited my answer but Marc's solution is better

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this stack overflow answer.  [AngularJS - How to structure a custom filter with ng-repeat to return items conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196161/angularjs-how-to-structure-a-custom-filter-with-ng-repeat-to-return-items-cond)
it clearly explains how to create a custom angular filter for use with ng-repeat. Once you understand this you will be able to filter out basically anything from an `ng-repeat`!