# AngularJS : Filter greater than a value using date

Tags: angularjs, date, filter

I have a json file who contains multiple events who have a start date.
I want to make a filter to display events who have a start date only greater than a date given by a user.

The input where the user give the date:

```
<label for="rechercheDate">Date de début</label>
<input type="text" id="rechercheDateDebut" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dateDebut" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
```

(I use the date picker from the UI bootstrap (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/))

The events and start date are display with:

```
<li ng-repeat="resultats in resultatsJSON.results">
    Start date: {{resultats.tra_start_date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}} 
    ....
```

To do what i want, i think i need to make a filter in my ng-repeat, something like:

```
<li ng-repeat="resultats in resultatsJSON.results |filter:resultats.tra_start_date>dateDebut">
```

This post [AngularJS : ng-repeat filter when value is greater than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081004/angular-ng-repeat-filter-when-value-is-greater-than) seems similar but is not applied to date format.How can i do that ?

This is a JSFiddle to illustrate my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/Daviloppeur/egf0kjzc/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [filter docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

> {{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator}}

You should use an Object for the expression and a comparator for checking dates:

```
$scope.gteComparator = function(a,b) {
  return new Date(a) >= new Date(b);
};
```

Use it like so:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in results | filter:{ start_date: start }:gteComparator>
```

Comment: it seems not works for me, added a console.log to see if gteComparator is call and nothing appear. I implemented gteComparator like this:                myApp.filter('gteComparator', function(a,b) {
  console.log("appel de gteComparator");
  return new Date(a) >= new Date(b);
});

Comment: @Ilan Frumer you save my life