# Angular ng-repeat filter with greater than

Tags: angularjs, select, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, minimum

I'm using angular to create a search property form, and I've got a select box with amount of bedrooms, how can I create a greater then filter? (for example: when 2 bedrooms selected, display all properties with 2 bedrooms or more)

The select box:

```
<select class="form-control" 
        name="bedrooms" 
        ng-model="Bedrooms" 
        ng-options="property.data.SubType as (property.data.Bedrooms + ' Bedrooms ('+ property.count +')') for property in properties  | unique:'Bedrooms' | orderBy:'data.Bedrooms'">
        <option value="">Minimum Bedrooms</option>
</select>
```

And the filter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="property in filtered = (properties | filterMultiple:{Address: Address, SubArea:SubArea, SubType:SubType} | filter:{Bedrooms:Bedrooms})|  orderBy:Address">
```

This is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcgeurts/odpw6c6q/)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081004/angular-ng-repeat-filter-when-value-is-greater-than

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/odpw6c6q/43/

In `ng-options` use `ng-options="property.data.Bedrooms as` instead of `ng-options="property.data.SubType as`
because `data.Bedrooms` is the property that contains number of bedrooms which should be stored in `ng-model`

In scope add this function

```
//Filter Function
    $scope.greaterThan = function(bedrooms) {
        return function(item) {                          
            if ( item['Bedrooms'] > bedrooms) {                
                return true;
            } else {                
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
```

In `ng-repeat` use `filter: greaterThan(Bedrooms)` instead of `filter:{Bedrooms:Bedrooms}`

Comment: Thanks for your help!

do you know how I can improve the filter to work better? at the moment, when some areas are selected, and then select a type, the rest of the options don't work anymore.

here's my updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcgeurts/odpw6c6q/)

Comment: It looks fine. What exactly is not working? You can vote and accept my answer if it is helpful :)