# ng-repeat multiple filter with number and date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using `ng-repeat` to draw table lines and I'm currently filtering on multiple text parameters. Here is a simplified example with fixed strings

```
<tr ng-repeat="thisOffer in offerList | filter: {name: 'hotel', id: 'H2O_'}"></tr>
```

This works fine and now I want to filter also on a number, testing if it's lower than a given value. Is it possible to use a filter like the following ones? I can't find anything similar in angular documentation but I can't believe a straightforward solution doesn't exist

```
<tr ng-repeat="thisOffer in offerList | filter: {name: 'hotel', id: 'H2O_', number: '<5' }"></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="thisOffer in offerList | filter: {name: 'hotel', id: 'H2O_'} | filter: 'thisOffer.number < 5' "></tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After applying this answer, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/22843/) work for you (inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24081564/492258))

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter: {name: 'John'} | filter: greaterThan('phone', 1)">
        <span>{{friend.name}}</span>
        <span>{{friend.phone}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, but it slows down incredibly the rendering. I fear the only way to accomplish this efficiently is using a custom `filter` :(

Comment: For that it should dig into angular source code or even better ask in a question if "custom filter slows down?". But i "think" it does not

Comment: I can make an analogy that cost of assigment in a for loop, which is considered zero.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter you can chain filters, so your second solution should work.

If not, please provide a fiddle so I can look into it

Comment: when `filter` takes a string input it looks for a match, it doesn't execute the expression, so that can't work

Comment: Ah ok, thought your question was about chaining filters, not how to set up a numeric filter. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35749798/4068027 for a solution to that.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a predicate function in the relevant scope, and use it in your ng-repeat, as in:

```
<tr ng-repeat="thisOffer in offerList | filter: lessThan('Number', 5)""></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function on the relevant scope:

```
$scope.greaterThan = function(prop, val){
    return function(item){
      return item[prop] > val;
    }
}
```

As a first argument, it takes a property name on the object. The second argument is an integer value.

Use it in your view like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="thisOffer in offerList | filter: greaterThan('Number', 0)">
```