# Filtering an array by number in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm wondering if I can do something like the code below in AngularJS. The goal is to filter the array by all ids >= the search id. Can I do the search inline or does it have to be done as a custom filter in javascript?

```
<div style="margin-top:5px;margin-left:30px;">
    <div>
        <div>ID</div>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>&nbsp;
        <input type="text" ng-model="listFoodItems.searchid" />
    </div>
    <table class="table table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Discount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot></tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in listFoodItems.fullitemdescs | filter: EntryId >= searchid">
                <td>{{row.EntryId}}</td>
                <td>{{row.ItemDesc}}</td>
                <td>{{row.ItemDisc}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You could have div(ng-if="row. EntryId > listFoodItems.searchid") to wrap around the tds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way make a custom filter like:

HTML

```
    <div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchid" />
       <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="person in people | filter:myFilter">
               {{person.id}}
               -
               {{person.name}}
           </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function MyCtrl($scope){

    $scope.people = [
        {id: 1, name: "Mark"},
        {id: 2, name: "John"},
        {id:3, name: "Joe"}
    ];
    $scope.myFilter = function(item){
        if(item.id >= $scope.searchid){
            return item;
        }
    };
}
```

here its my fiddle with example: https://jsfiddle.net/javierif/mmoo3s8m/

Comment: Is there a difference between what you have and: `return item.id >= $scope.searchid;` ?

Comment: because i binding input with ng-model="searchid" and it stored in $scope.searchid

Answer (score 0):

First, create a function

```
$scope.lessThan = function(prop, val){
    return function(item){
        return item[prop] < val;
    }
}
```

Next, in your `ng-repeat`

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in listFoodItems.fullitemdescs | filter: lessThan('EntryId', searchid)">
```

Original answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24081564/5141584