# simple filter out objects with a certain property integer value angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I want to filter out all objects with quantity less than 1 and I had to make a custom filter in order to achieve that. I was hoping that there was a simpler solution to the problem than a custom filter.

The following will **not** work:

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products | filter: {quantity: '!0'}">
```

This will filter out 10,20 and so on in addition to 0.

I ended up using this custom filter:

```
app.filter('quantityFilter', function() {
  return function( products) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(products, function(product) {
        if(product.quantity > 0 ){
            filtered.push(product);
        }
    });
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products | quantityFilter">
```

Is there a smoother solution to this? Like (**does not work**):

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products | filter: {quantity: >0}">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS : ng-repeat filter when value is greater than](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081004/angularjs-ng-repeat-filter-when-value-is-greater-than)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing a separate filter you can use a predicate function for the filter. This is described in detail in the AngularJS [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

so for you this becomes:

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products | filter:noZeroQuantity">
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.noZeroQuantity = function(value, index, array) {
    return value.quantity !== 0;
}
```

I wrote an example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/2209/).