# Remove or hide specific items in select list using ng-options in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to remove/hide a few options from a select list that uses ng-options.  In my list I have 18 items and I simply want to remove 6 of them from the list but without deleting them (their in my database being used elsewhere).  I don't want the user to be able to see them in this list.  Is there a way to loop thru and hide them using ng-options?

**In my html:**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-{{model.data.colSize}}" ng-show="model.data.passionPointFilter">
            <select class="region-filter form-control"
                    ng-model="model.selections.passionPoint" ng-options="item.id as item.title for item in model.passionPoints.items">
                <option value="">All Interest</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

**In my Controller:**

```
if (model.data.passionPointFilter) {
            txThingsToDo.loadAll().then(function (thingstodo) {
                model.passionPoints.loading = false;
                model.passionPoints.items = thingstodo.results;
            });
```

I would like to remove for example the last 3

```
<select class="region-filter form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" 
                    ng-model="model.selections.passionPoint" ng-options="item.id as item.title for item in model.passionPoints.items">
            <option value="" class="">All Interest</option>
            <option value="0" label="Ranches &amp; Rodeos">Ranches &amp; Rodeos</option>
            <option value="1" label="Beaches">Beaches</option>
            <option value="2" label="Arts &amp; Culture">Arts &amp; Culture</option>
            <option value="3" label="Family">Family</option>
            <option value="4" label="Golf">Golf</option>
            <option value="5" label="Historic">Historic</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: You could use a custom filter, [this link might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081004/angularjs-ng-repeat-filter-when-value-is-greater-than).

Comment: @Santhi Kumar - I tried your code, however nothing happens. I even tried to console.log it out and still no affect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter in ng-options
`<select class="region-filter form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" ng-model="model.selections.passionPoint" ng-options="item.id as item.title for item in model.passionPoints.items | filter: filterItems">`

"filterItems" is a function which should be in the controller

```
$scope.filterItems = function(item){
   //write the logic based on the requirement.
   return item.id <= $scope.model.passionPoints.items.length-3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ng-if** or **ng-show**

For example:

```
    var myArray = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'value1'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'value2'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'value3'
    }];

    <span ng-repeat="obj in myArray" ng-if="obj.id > 2">{{obj.name}}</span>
    <span ng-repeat="obj in myArray" ng-show="obj.id > 2">{{obj.name}</span>
```

In the above example ***value3*** will be printed to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create an if statement to loop through and remove unwanted select statements.  Its a round about way, but it works perfectly.  I didnt have to modify anything within the html.  If there is a better way, I'm open for suggestions.

```
if (model.data.passionPointFilter) {
            txThingsToDo.loadAll().then(function (thingstodo) {
                model.passionPoints.loading = false;
                for (var i = 0; i < thingstodo.results.length; i++) {
                    //Hide unwanted passionpoints from list.
                    if (thingstodo.results[i].id != "tex-plorer" &&
                        thingstodo.results[i].id != "films" &&
                        thingstodo.results[i].id != "tx-food-and-drink" &&
                        thingstodo.results[i].id != "tx-music" &&
                        thingstodo.results[i].id != "tx-beaches" &&
                        thingstodo.results[i].id != "tx-outdoors" &&
                        thingstodo.results[i].id != "chisholmtrail") {
                        model.passionPoints.items.push(thingstodo.results[i]);
                    }
                }
            });
```