# Fetching Specific user from firebase

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I have 10 users in my Firebase user node, they are

1. Diva
2. Ziva
3. Destiny
4. Daniel
5. James
6. Zionnite   **(This is Me)**
7. Jessy
8. Johan
9. Precious
10. Kings

and I have a code that lists all users from my user list, the code:

service.js:

```
app.service("ListAllUserService",function($q, $rootScope, $ionicPopup, $firebaseAuth, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, $localStorage, $ionicLoading){
    var self    ={
        'data'  : '',
        'Loading':  true,
        "hasMore":true,
        "page":10,
        "next_page":3,
        'users' :   '',
        'lastKnownDomainValue': [],
        'ListUser': function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
            var usersRef  = new Firebase("https://bigzill.firebaseio.com/users");
            var usersRef2  = new Firebase("https://bigzill.firebaseio.com");

            var authData = usersRef.getAuth();
            $rootScope.scrollRef = new Firebase.util.Scroll(usersRef,"username");

            if(authData){
                    self.users    = $firebaseArray($rootScope.scrollRef);
                                        $rootScope.scrollRef.scroll.next(self.page);
                                        self.Loading   =false;
                                    deferred.resolve(self.users);
            }else{
                console.log("User not Authenticated");
                deferred.reject(data);
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
    self.ListUser();
    return  self;
});
```

controller.js:

```
app.controller('ListAllUserCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $ionicPopup, $firebaseAuth, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, PresenceService, $localStorage, $ionicLoading, ListAllUserService){

    $scope.Get  =ListAllUserService;

    $scope.LoadAllUser  =function(){
        $ionicLoading.show({template:'Loading...'});
        $scope.Get.ListUser().then(function(data){
            $scope.users    =data;
            console.log($scope.users);
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        });
    }
    $scope.LoadAllUser();

});
```

I want to make sure that the logged in user is not displayed from the return results.

1. Diva
2. Ziva
3. Destiny
4. Daniel
5. James
6. Jessy
7. Johan
8. Precious
9. Kings

**You see zionnite is no longer in the list.**

Comment: once you have loged in you can push that particular username into an array and the you can check the string in each or the names you are getting and do not push that name into array so that you can avoid duplicate and then you can push the remaining names into that array and also ng-repeat does not allow duplicate.

Comment: @MohanGopi , thank you for your time but can you please show it me with code (it will really help alot)... thanks again

Comment: Client-side filtering is probably easiest for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671714/how-to-filter-out-a-user-using-ng-repeat-within-firebase-and-angularfire

Comment: yes you are right are you getting those name from backend

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen , thank you sir. i will do that right away

Comment: HURRAY.... its working now.. thanks to you for your help