# Angular filtering based on the field value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have table that I am performing ng-repeat and getting the data from server

```
<tr ng-repeat="assetsdetail in detailAssets | filter: {IND_RECORD_TYPE : !RUNNING}:true">
        <td>{{assetsdetail.MASTER_ASSET_TYPE}}</td>
        <td>{{assetsdetail.MINOR_ASSET_TYPE}}</td>
        <td>{{assetsdetail.DETAIL_ASSET_TYPE}}</td>
        <td>{{assetsdetail.PRODUCT_DESC}}</td>
        <td>{{assetsdetail.VENDOR_NAME}}</td>
        <td>{{assetsdetail.IND_RECORD_TYPE}}</td>
      </tr>
```

What I want to achieve here is that I want all the data EXCEPT the one that has
IND_RECORD_TYPE of RUNNING. I have so far failed to achieve this, is their  a simple way to do it in view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular JS filter not equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666366/angular-js-filter-not-equals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't need a filter for that. A simple **ng-show** can do the trick as follows:

```
<tr ng-repeat="assetsdetail in detailAssets" ng-hide="assetsdetail.IND_RECORD_TYPE == 'RUNNING'">
    <td>{{assetsdetail.MASTER_ASSET_TYPE}}</td>
    <td>{{assetsdetail.MINOR_ASSET_TYPE}}</td>
    <td>{{assetsdetail.DETAIL_ASSET_TYPE}}</td>
    <td>{{assetsdetail.PRODUCT_DESC}}</td>
    <td>{{assetsdetail.VENDOR_NAME}}</td>
    <td>{{assetsdetail.IND_RECORD_TYPE}}</td>
</tr>
```

However, if you are adamant on using a filter here's how you can do it:

```
<tr ng-repeat="assetsdetail in detailAssets | filter: filterItem">
    <td>{{assetsdetail.MASTER_ASSET_TYPE}}</td>
    <td>{{assetsdetail.MINOR_ASSET_TYPE}}</td>
    <td>{{assetsdetail.DETAIL_ASSET_TYPE}}</td>
    <td>{{assetsdetail.PRODUCT_DESC}}</td>
    <td>{{assetsdetail.VENDOR_NAME}}</td>
    <td>{{assetsdetail.IND_RECORD_TYPE}}</td>
</tr>
```

And in your **controller**, declare a function 'filterItem' as follows:

```
$scope.filterItem = function(item) {
    if(item.IND_RECORD_TYPE == 'RUNNING') {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

What this function does is it takes each **'item'** of the array and returns true if you want to display it or false if you want to hide it. The **'item'** in your case is **'assetsdetail'**

Answer (score 1):

change

```
filter: {IND_RECORD_TYPE : !RUNNING}
```

to

```
filter: {IND_RECORD_TYPE : '!RUNNING'}
```