# Angularjs: How to apply NOT filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angular-filters

How to apply a NOT filter in the following example?

Tried `$filter('filter')(users,{ranks: {id: '!' + '15'},true)` and `$filter('filter')(users, !{ranks: {id:15}},true)` but nothing seems to work.

The aim here is to not get user with id = 15 in the filtered array

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$filter) {

  $scope.users = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'John Doe',
      ranks: [ 
        { id: 1, name: 'Admin'},
        { id: 2, name: 'Doe' }
        ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Barbara Doe',
      ranks: [ { id: 15, name: 'Wife'}, { id: 2, name: 'Doe' }],
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Jane Doe',
      ranks: [ { id: 16, name: 'Wife'}, { id: 17, name: 'Doe' }],
    },
  ];

  $scope.filter = $filter('filter')($scope.users, {ranks: {id: !15}},true);


});
```

**HTML:**

```
<p>HTML Filter: List of users without having a rank with id: 15</p>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{ranks: {id: '!' + '15'}} : true"> 
        {{ user }}
      </li>
    </ul>

    <p>Controller Filter: List of users without having a rank with id: 15</p>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="user in filter "> 
        {{ user }}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

**Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/73lLDpn3uLHozObKn539?p=preview

Comment: @Tushar Tried this $scope.filter = $filter('filter')($scope.users, ranks.id != 15,true); But it is invalid syntax

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to filter out users where their ranks property contains {id: 15}, you may not have a choice but to write a custom filter, or a predicate function to do that (because this is not a traditional == or != comparison)

Here's an example using a predicate function:

```
     ranksContainsId15 = function(user, index, users){
        // Look for rank.id === 15
        for(var i=0; i < user.ranks.length; i++){
          if(user.ranks[i].id === 15){
            return false; // so this user will NOT be included
          }
        }

        // no rank.id === 15 found, so this user will be included
        return true;
      }

      $scope.filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.users, ranksContainsId15);
```

I've updated the example to show all users, then show users that don't have a rank.id == 15 in their ranks array

http://plnkr.co/edit/6x3OEzSiDfIziAnVQ0Em?p=preview

To create predicate functions with a programmable ID, use a function to create them

```
createPredicateFn = function(id){
    return function(user, index, users){
            for(var i=0; i < user.ranks.length; i++){
              if(user.ranks[i].id === id){
                return false;
              }
            }

            return true;
    }
}

$scope.filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.users, createPredicateFn(15));
```

Comment: How can I have this predicate function as a global predicate? Custom filter?

Comment: @shyamalparikh I think the most natural solution is a custom filter defined in the app module. Otherwise maybe put it into your UserService service? e.g. as UserService.getUsersWithoutRankId(rankId) and use that directly instead of filtering it in the scope. Because putting a filter and/or its predicate function into $scope or $rootScope isn't really a good idea. I think a good controller is a _thin_ controller that delegates other things to a service e.g. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom filter to filter item manually:

```
.filter('customFilter', function() {
  return function(array, numberToSkip) {
    var result = [];

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      var arrayItemContainsId = false;

      for (j = 0; j < array[i].ranks.length; j++) {
        if (array[i].ranks[j].id === numberToSkip) {
          arrayItemContainsId = true;
        }
      }

      if (arrayItemContainsId == false) {
        result.push(array[i]);
      }
    }

    return result;
  };
});
```

and use this like this:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="user in users | customFilter: 15"> 
      {{ user }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well that is an alternative but angularjs has an option of NOT filtering then why not use it? Check this:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666366/angular-js-filter-not-equals

Comment: @shyamalparikh Most likely because you are testing for a container having a given element, as opposed to being _equal_ / _not equal_ to something, and what you're doing is making ng test user.ranks (which is a list) against an object ({id: 15}), which isn't what you want. A custom filter like Dawid, or a custom predicate function like in my answer is way to implement this

Answer (score -1):

You have implemented the not filter slightly wrong. Use this instead

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | filter: !{ranks: {id:15}} : true">
```